# Stage 2 ecmaScript, unexpected token on destructuring inside class

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Using stage 2 es I have a React component with a prop.contest that matches this PropType

```
ContestPreview.propTypes = {
  contest: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    categoryName: PropTypes.string,
    contestName: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

And the component is:

```
class ContestPreview extends React.Component {
  { contest } = this.props;
  { contestName, categoryName } = contest;

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(contestName);
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="link ContestPreview" role="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <div className="category-name">
          {categoryName}
        </div>
        <div className="contest-name">
          {contestName}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting an error from eslint `unexpected token` which points to the opening { of my destructing assignment.  In ES6 I was comfortable with making a constructor and setting my properties in there. Is this normal for the current state of **stage2**?  I can solve this by

`contest = this.props.contest;` and referencing `this.contest.categoryName` instead. However my eslinting rules do complain about **react/destructuring-assignment** The code runs fine.  Im only using stage 2 because the Lynda.com course I am doing is using this.

My question is, what would be the best approach to getting the destructuring working?  Not sure at this point if I changed the project configuration, how I would have to modify things back to es6.

Comment: Destructure the properties in the render method, and not in the class's body

Comment: Thank you that indeed works though now If i want to access the properties in other methods I need to do more destructing.  I thought about storing the data on the state, I guess im confused as to the syntax of stage2.  Is this typical behaviour? Is destructing inside render and other methods the best way?  Maybe I am over thinking this.

Comment: You can't destructure into class properties like, and you don't want to do that, because then they won't update when the properties do. You can destructure whenever you need the properties.

Comment: That makes sense now , I never thought about it that way.  If you post this as an answer I will accept it.